# Assigning an array through foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
    // ex: $field = "1f_fieldname";
    if($field[1] == "f")
    {
        // $field[0] is numeric
        $i = $field[0];
        $data = array($i => $value);
    }
}
```

the array $data will only print the last element assigned only.
ex:

```
print_r($data);
```

prints the following:

> array(
> [3] => "value3"
> )

instead of:

> array(
> [0] => "value1", 
>   [1] => "value2", 
> [2] => "value2", 
> [3] => "value3"
> )

What's wrong with it ??

EDIT:
When I print the array from inside the foreach, it prints the whole elements.
But when I print it outside the foreach, it will print only the last one.

Comment: Cause `$field[0]` is not `"f"`?

Comment: declare the empty array at top of the line like $data = array(); then try

Comment: i did it actually, i thought of that too, but still the same problem

Comment: @u_mulder i made an echo statement inside the condition and it printed so the condition works

Comment: could you share what's  data is in your $_POST array

Comment: $_POST = array("field1"=>"value1", "field2"=>"value2" ..etc);

Comment: Then it should not be printing a numerically indexed array, So what else is **really going on in your real code**

Comment: I think you if condition is wrong $field is key of $_POST array and it must be a string and you are treating as array

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST)` and edit that result into your question

Comment: @aman You can treat strings like arrays of single characters so `if($field[0] == "f"){` is a valid statement

Comment: @RiggsFolly i edited the code so it prints numeric indexes. i spent the whole night looking for solution i found myself in a maze

Comment: **Then SHOW US ALL THE RELEVANT CODE** If you only show us bits all you will get are **guesses based on what we can see** And people will soon start to ignore the question or start offering close votes

Comment: I agree with @RiggsFolly

Comment: Use `$data[] = $value` to push onto an array. When you use `$i` your way, you'll get gaps in the indexes.

Comment: If you're getting different results when you print inside and outside the `foreach`, something outside the `foreach` must be changing the array. It doesn't happen by itself.

Comment: **HAY** ___Hang on___ The question has just completely changed. **What is really going on here** This is not a movable feast you know

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited the question and added the real code in my application

Comment: @Barmar i did that without positive results

Comment: Are you looking at `$field[0]` or `$field[1]` please check again?????

Comment: You are overwriting the `$data` variable in this statement `$data = array($i => $value);` use `$data[] = array($i => $value);`

Comment: `$field[0]` is to retrieve the number and `$field[1]` to check if the letter "f" is next to the number

Comment: **ALSO** Please show us an example of the $_POST array you are processing **PLEASE**

Comment: Oh that's Cool  it's solved ! `$data[] = array($i => $value);` is the solution.

Comment: @R00t_R3z It doesn't give the desired result that you show in the question. have you changed what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
$data = array($i => $value);
```

It replaces the entire array with a new array containing just a single element. It should be:

```
$data[$i] = $value;
```

to add a new element to the array. But if you have two keys in `$_POST` with the same number as the first character (e.g. `1f_fieldA` and `1f_fieldB`), the later one will replace the first one.

Comment: Now I finally prized the real code out of the OP I am still getting confused by the previous iterations. I have deleted my answer and will now go and take a chill pill